# form_for [@nested, @resource], remote => true responding with format.html rails 3.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2, form-for, nested-form-for

Can't get an ajax form_for to respect the format.js respond_to only responds with format.html. Any help much appreciated.

**view**

This view is called in partial by AJAX and then the user submits the form. Could the initial ajax call confuse the 'remote:true' of this form?

```
<%= form_for([@nested, @nested.resources.new], remote: true) do |i|%>
  <%= i.hidden_field :inviter_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <%= i.hidden_field :fb_pic_url, value: f['pic_square'] %>
  <%= i.hidden_field :name, value: f['name'] %>
  <%= i.hidden_field :uid, value: f['uid'] %>
  <%= i.submit "Invite", class:"btn btn-success invite_button" %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :nested do 
  resources :resources
end
```

**controller**

```
def create
  code code code

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @nested, notice: "Successfully Posted Nested" }
    format.json { render json: @nested, status: :created, location: @nested }
    format.js { render :nothing => true }
  end
end
```

**create.js.erb**
Present but empty

**application.html**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: What accept headers are sent in the request?

Comment: "HTTP_ACCEPT"=>"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You are saying that after submit form_for you are getting html response?

Comment: Correct, it should be receiving a js request and responding with the js template from the format.js line but instead it is receiving an html request and giving an html response.

Comment: If you inspect the form, does it have 
    data-remote="true"
as part of it?

Comment: @ajbraus, I'm having the same exact problem as you are even after following the instructions of the answer below without success.  Did you get this working?  Was it really just making the changes suggested in the answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the rails built-in non-intrusive jquery plugin included, since its responsible for making the `remote: true` code work.

also, if you want to render the template `create.js.erb` you need to leave the row `format.js` without a block:

```
respond_to do |format|
  ...
  format.js
end
```

Besides that, are you using the other response formats? `json` and `html`? if not, try to avoid putting them.

Comment: I am having the same exact problem as this person (same exact!), and I have satisfied all your suggestions in your answer and am still getting the issue.  Could you please take a look at the question I've already written here: [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545354/remote-true-option-for-form-for-working-for-new-action-but-not-create-action/22673922#22673922)?