# remote: true option for form_for working for new action, but not create action

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

### Update:

This has been resolved!  This was a difficult one as it wasn't very easy to debug at all.  But in noticing that I had a form tag within a form tag, my gracious "answerer" pointed out that this needed to be fixed regardless of whether this was the root cause of the problem or not.  Please keep in mind that I agree with him that `nested attributes` is definitely the way to go on this one, however because this is a school project at this point in time, I elected to move the inner form outside the outer form for now to get it doing what I expected.  This involved changing some of the code you see below.  But I will not post that new code because, again, I agree that `nested attributes` is the way to go in this situation.  When I get the time, that will be my next goal for this project.

### Original Question:

I'm using Rails 4 and I have nested resources like this:

```
resources :data do
  resources :todo_items
end
```

In the edit page of a `datum` object, I intend for the user to have the ability to add  `todo_item`s to the `datum` object via ajax.  When you click on the "add todo item" button, my form for creating a new `todo_item` is requested, and upon filling out the required fields, the user is able to click add and I intend for another request to be made that will display the `todo_item` as a partial that includes a checkbox for the user to show whether it is complete or not.  The new form comes up fine, but I get an `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error when I click the add button to display the newly created `todo_item`.  Here is the code I'm using:

app/views/data/_form.html.erb

```
...
<%= link_to 'Add ToDo', new_datum_todo_item_path(@datum.id), remote: true %>
...
```

app/controllers/todo_items_controller.rb

```
class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @datum = Datum.find(params[:datum_id])
    @todo = TodoItem.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def create
    @datum = Datum.find(params[:datum_id])
    @todo = @datum.todo_items.create!(todo_item_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  private

    def todo_item_params
      params.require(:todo_item).permit(:task, :content, :done)
    end
end
```

app/views/todo_items/_form.html.erb (the 'new' form)

```
<div id="<%= datum.id %>-<%= todo.id %>" class="panel todo-item">
  <%= bootstrap_form_for([datum, todo], remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :done, value: false %>
    <%= f.text_field :task, hide_label: true, placeholder: 'task' %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, hide_label: true, placeholder: 'content' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Add', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

app/views/todo_items/_todo.html.erb

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for([datum, todo], remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.check_box :done, hide_label: true %>
  <div><%= todo.task %></div>
  <div><%= todo.content %></div>
<% end %>
```

app/views/todo_items/new.js.erb (the response that is working)

```
$('.panel-body').append("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'form', locals: { datum: @datum, todo: @todo }) %>");
```

app/views/todo_items/create.js.erb (the response that is not working)

```
$("#<%= @datum.id %>-<%= @todo.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'todo_items/todo', locals: { datum: @datum, todo: @todo }) %>");
```

Could someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?  I only intend to `respond_to` `format.js`.  Both forms include `remote: true`.  I feel like I'm missing something pretty silly here, but I have been trying to figure this out for a long time now.  Thanks!  Please let me know if I need to provide any further information...

### Update:

Here is what appears in my server log with the new and create requests:

```
Started GET "/data/532799016a616b1786040000/todo_items/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-20 16:05:04 -0600
Processing by TodoItemsController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"datum_id"=>"532799016a616b1786040000"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} runtime: 0.4793ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=datums_app_development collection=data selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('532799016a616b1786040000')} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.4106ms
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered todo_items/_form.html.erb (8.8ms)
  Rendered todo_items/new.js.erb (14.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 15.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/data/532799016a616b1786040000/todo_items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-20 16:05:11 -0600
Processing by TodoItemsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"stsyxQfAuzPa1BGnOx2cAuagZqFuSHF6jfos9/euw94=", "todo_item"=>{"done"=>"false", "task"=>"Task", "content"=>"Content"}, "commit"=>"Add", "datum_id"=>"532799016a616b1786040000"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=datums_app_development collection=data selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('532799016a616b1786040000')} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.5380ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=datums_app_development collection=data selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('532799016a616b1786040000')} update={"$push"=>{"todo_items"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('532b66176a616b4160010000'), "task"=>"Task", "content"=>"Content", "done"=>false, "updated_at"=>2014-03-20 22:05:11 UTC, "created_at"=>2014-03-20 22:05:11 UTC}}} flags=[]
                         COMMAND      database=datums_app_development command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 1.1161ms
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 8ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat:
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:372:in `retrieve_collector_from_mimes'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:189:in `respond_to'
  app/controllers/todo_items_controller.rb:13:in `create'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__1881092772621756057__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__936815074203488114__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/jake/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/jake/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/jake/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Can you share the server log generated when you click the Add button on new form.

Comment: @KirtiThorat, I've added my server log.  As you can see, it is expecting HTML rather than JS for some reason...

Comment: @KirtiThorat, did the server log help any?  I'm still thoroughly confused as to why `Processing by TodoItemsController#create as HTML` appears when I initiate the create action, as I have a `format.js` in the `respond_to` block of the controller, `remote: true` in the view, and a `data-remote="true"` that appears in the html if I inspect it with chrome developer tools.  Does this have anything to do with the fact that I'm trying to use ajax on something that doesn't exist until after a previous ajax call is used?  Do I need to refresh anything to have it recognize the second ajax call?  Thanks

Comment: it seems like the form isn't submitting via ajax. make sure that when you hit submit an ajax request is fired. you can do it via chrome dev tools. if not - than you should find out why `remote: true` isn't working in your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible error is related to dom objects selectors. Try with:

```
$('#<%= @datum.id %>-<%= @todo.id %>').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'todo_items/todo', locals: { datum: @datum, todo: @todo }) %>");
```

Using `jquery` selector by `#id` instead of by `.class`. Since you have added instances info (`id="<%= datum.id %>-<%= todo.id %>"`) to `id` attribute:

```
<div id="<%= datum.id %>-<%= todo.id %>" class="panel todo-item">
```

**Update after review source code linked in comments**

You are using a `form` inside a `form` and that's incorrect, it's **unsupported** by browsers and it could cause unpredictable behavior, like in your case.

You should change a bit your approach/implementation. In this case you probably need to work with [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for).

[Here a related RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).

Comment: I'm sorry, can you clarify what the error is?  Am I not able select dom objects via their id?

Comment: $('#foo'): selects via id; $(".foo"): selects via class. I'm going to edit answer with some clarifications.

Comment: you are right, I didn't have the proper ID selector.  However, that did not help it recognize the `data-remote="true"` attribute and expect JS instead of HTML.

Comment: It seems ok, could you provide us a sample app to reproduce it?

Comment: You can see this happening if you visit [my site on heroku](https://datums.herokuapp.com).  If you sign up, and then navigate to your Datums, you can create a datum, edit it, and start adding todo items.  You will experience the issue in that workflow.

Comment: I think I've found what is causing the error. Please see edited answer.

Comment: That is a very good call on your part.  Are you suggesting the nested attributes approach so that I can keep my new todo_item "form" inside the panel like I currently have it?  Could I also move that new todo_item form outside of the datum form and have it work?  I've just watched 2 videos on the nested attributes form stuff and it is a bit over my head right now.  I'm hoping I can get this to work with two different forms that are not embedded within each other.  What do you think?

Comment: A lot of questions @JakeSmith, and all of them different to OP! I think the better solution is to make it with `nested attributes`, it's the natural way in rails. Of course, you can do it without it, just adding second form out of current form and wrap parameters manually in the controller (more or less as you do it now). If you are using `.create!`, remember, to create multiple resources you should send and array of hashes. Anyway, original question was solved, problem is caused by nested forms, so I think answer should be accepted.

Comment: My goal is to get to the nested attributes.  I need to finish what's required for the school project and then I plan on working on that right after.  Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I think rail's `remote: true` option is "black magic" and I never use it - It's more trouble than it's worth. Your question is a good example.

If I where you, I would use regular javascript instead of using that particular rails bit. It's more verbose, but also more clear, and easier to debug.

I can't program it for you, though.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

The key is here
`Processing by TodoItemsController#create as HTML`. In your create action you're only responding to the js mime-type but the request is being processed as html. Hence the unknown format error. Either add `format.html` to the action or you can force it to be a js mime type by add `format: :js` to your form.

Comment: My intent is to only handle :js.  I tried adding the `format: :js` to the form already, and that did not change the error message I received.  But could you tell me why I would put `format: :js` rather than `remote: true`?  I put both options in for the form_for helper, and it still gives me that same error message.

Comment: to clarify, I tried `format: :js` as a `form_for` option in both forms independently.  If I place this option in the second form, I experience no difference in regards to getting that error.  If I place this option in the first form however, upon submission, my entire page is replaced with the raw jQuery contents of my `create.js.erb` file.

Comment: do you have any other ideas?  If you read my question, you will understand my intent.  I tried specifying the `format: :js` as you suggested and you can read in my previous comment the outcome of that.  But you seem to understand this part of Rails, so I was hoping you could provide more suggestions?  Thanks!